# MySQL search with multiple category id

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I got a talbe like this

```
category_table

cat_id   |   cat_name
---------+--------------
1        |  cat 1'
---------+--------------
2        |  cat 2
---------+--------------
3        |  cat 3
---------+--------------
4        |  cat 4
---------+--------------
5        |  cat 5
```

Another table called item table as follows

```
item_table

item_id   |   item_name    |  cat_id
----------+----------------+-----------
1         |  name of item  |  2
2         |  name of item  |  1
3         |  name of item  |  2
4         |  name of item  |  3
5         |  name of item  |  2
6         |  name of item  |  4
```

I have got the following query for select in item_table

```
SELECT * FROM item_table WHERE cat_id=2
```

I got a category id array like this

```
$cats=array("2","3","3");
```

My question is how to perform a "multiple category" search using the above mentioned array ? Means I want select all items with category id 2,3,4.

Comment: Where does "4" come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `In Operator` of `MYSQL`:

```
SELECT * FROM item_table WHERE cat_id IN(2,3,4)
```

If you want to get result with join of tables then you can use:

```
SELECT t1.item_id, t1.item_name, t1.cat_id, t2.cat_name 
FROM item_table t1 
INNER JOIN category_table t2 ON t1.cat_id = t2.cat_id
WHERE t1.cat_id IN(2,3,4)
```